# google app engine datastore Go Query with "in" operator

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Using Query in App Engine Datastore, how do I specify to fetch keys that match a property with variable values?

```
var Person struct {
   name string
   department string  
}

//Query
q := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("department = ", "department1").KeysOnly()
```

In the above query, instead of **"="** operator, I want "IN" operator to specify more than 1 department value i.e fetch all person keys who belong to department1, department2, department3 etc.

Is this possible with 1 Query? Or do I need to make 1 query for each department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other runtimes allow "IN" operator for datastore queries. It is, however, just a convenience: under the hood, the [datastore makes individual queries for each element in the list](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/12/queries-with-and-in-filters.html).

If you have a relatively small number of entities, it may be more efficient to retrieve all of them and then filter the results based on the "department" property, rather than issues N queries to search for N possible departments.